# Why doesn't my binary search implementation work?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, search, binary-search

I'm trying to get my binary search implementation to work with a `List()`. I understand that there is already a `List<T>.BinarySearch()` method however I'm trying to get it to work with my own code.

In the input file the 1st line is the `Name`, 2nd is `Age`, 3rd is `Height`, 4th is `Weight`:

```
Monty Reyes
28
1700
70.7
Kier Burke
45
1800
93.5
```

etc.

The current code is:

```vbnet
Public Class Search
    Public Class Patient
        Property Name As String
        Property Age As Integer
        Property Weight As Double
        Property Height As Integer
        Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
            Return String.Format("{0}: {1} years old, {2} mm, {3} kg", Name, Age, Height, Weight)
        End Function
    End Class
    Dim Lowest, Highest As Integer
    Dim MidIndex As Integer
    Dim FoundTarget As Boolean
    'Set RequiredName As a string variable
    Dim RequiredName As String
    'Set PositionOfTarget As an integer variable
    Dim PositionOfTarget As Integer
    Public Sub btnFindName_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFindName.Click
        Dim patients As New List(Of Patient)
        Dim data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\cag17\Desktop\Vb Major Project\Patient Data.txt")
        Dim patient = New Patient()
        For index = 0 To data.Length - 1 Step 4
            patient.Name = data(index)
            patient.Age = data(index + 1)
            patient.Height = data(index + 2)
            patient.Weight = data(index + 3)
            patients.Add(patient)
        Next
        FoundTarget = False
        RequiredName = txtPatientName.Text
        Lowest = 0
        Highest = patients.Count - 2
        While FoundTarget = False And Lowest <= Highest
            CalculateMiddleOfIndex()
            If RequiredName = patients(MidIndex).Name Then
                FoundTarget = True
                PositionOfTarget = MidIndex
            Else
                If RequiredName < patients(MidIndex).Name Then
                    Highest = (MidIndex - 1)
                Else
                    Lowest = (MidIndex + 1)
                End If
            End If
        End While
        If FoundTarget = True Then
            txtPatient.Text = patients(PositionOfTarget).Name
        Else
            txtPatient.Text = RequiredName & " was not found"
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub CalculateMiddleOfIndex()
        'MidIndex is equal to Highest + Lowest divided by 2
        MidIndex = (Highest + Lowest) / 2
    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is that whenever a `Name` is searched for despite the `Patient` 100% being in the list, it still returns `"RequiredName was not found"`. `FoundTarget` never ends up being set to `True`, so something might be wrong with the line, `If RequiredName = patients(MidIndex).Name Then`. If someone can give me a heads up on where I've gone wrong it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What specific problem(s) are you having with the current code and where?

Comment: No error appears when the code is run, however I'm receiving the wrong result. When a name is inputted that is known to be in the list, it still returns the result "RequiredName was not found". I'm assuming If RequiredName = patients(MidIndex).Name Then, has a problem somewhere.

Comment: The first and most obvious problem I see is that your data is not sorted; `"Monty Reyes"` sorts after `"Kier Burke"`. Binary search — and this is true of `List.BinarySearch()`, too — **requires** the input collection be sorted by the search value. You're also creating a single `Patient` outside of the `For` loop; since you're using the same `Patient` for every iteration, `patients` will consist of `data.Length / 4` references to the _same_ `Patient` with its properties set to those of the last patient in `Patient Data.txt`. Instead, move `Dim patient = New Patient()` inside the loop.

Comment: Oh thanks that worked, I originally had the patient inside the loop, I didn't know it would be so disastrous outside the loop, nor did I know the list needed to be sorted for BinarySearch to work. Thanks so much for the help!